# Package Name has not been set up correctly

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am making a game on Unity following this tutorial on YouTube:

I am brand new to Unity and Android Game Development, in the video I got to 35:16 and we are building the scenes and I clicked build and it is starting to load but when it gets to half-way done I get this error as seen in the image "Package Name has not been set up correctly

Please set the Package Name in the Player Settings.
The value must follow the convention
'com.YourCompanyName.YourProductName' and can
contain alphanumeric characters and underscore.
Each segment must not start with a numeric character or underscore."

Now, I am a 13 year old developer so I am quite young, I am not understanding what it is asking me to do and I don't know how to fix it, if a person could help me I would be so greatful... If needed we could go on Discord, Skype or Team Viewer to help me.

[image]

Comment: Wow quite good! 13 Years old is good for programming. If you mind to collaborate with me, then that's off to go! (I'm 12 years old programmer (NOW)) Check out my project (programming language) https://github.com/Faran2007/FSCMD

Answer (score 17):

In the latest Unity version, to fix that problem you need to go to Edit > Project Settings > Player .

Because you're building for Android, you select the Android icon.

[image: Unity Project Settings]

We can find, under Identification, Package Name.

[image: Unity Package Name]

The Package Name has to [follow some rules](http://answers.unity.com/answers/619791/view.html).

> Domain like structure with at least 3 parts. Usually start with
>   "com.COMPANY.APPNAME"
>
> You can use alphanumeric characters and underscores only.
>
> Each domain level must not start with a number.

For instances, you can change to "com.android.game".

This fixes the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Edit > Project Settings > Player. There should be a textbox in there labeled "Bundle Identifier" set it to something like "com.Fireboy.MyFirstGame" and then build.

Also, when you're ready to release to production you'll need to use the "Publish Settings" section to sign your apk in release mode. By default Unity signs it in Debug mode, which Google Play will not allow you to submit.

Comment: Note: if you do not own the website `Fireboy.com` then do not set your bundle identifier to `com.Fireboy.*`. You can put whatever you'd like here, it just needs to be specific to you. `game.Fireboy.*` works just fine.

Comment: @Draco18s I am guessing it is the bit that says Company Name
Product Name.

Comment: @Draco18s NVM it is just called Identification